# Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: TypeError: sequelize.import is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase

[this is issue I am facing while running my functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NDLm.png)

I am using windows 10 64bit, Nodejs version 16.16.0,
using this (firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions) commend to run the function.
I have updated the node version to fix, but not worked for me.

Comment: Are you trying to start the FIrebase functions emulator?

Comment: Please post the code as a text not an image.